# How can I change multiple files in different directories in Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, directory, append

I am working on a program using Python as my programming language, and I was just wondering if there was any possible way to change multiple files in different directories, without having to manually specify each directory.

For example I have 2 files in 2 different directories. File 1 is in 'data/fileOne/file.txt' and File 2 is in 'data/fileTwo/file.txt'. The text in File one is 'Hello-I-am-a-file' and the text in File two is 'Hello-I-am-file-two'.

How would I add something to both files using as little code as possible.

Comment: "without having to manually specify each directory" Then how would system know which files to write?

Comment: I'm basically asking how to scan a certain directory for a file name. All the files are the same name, so how would I scan the 'data' folder to find them files and append them!

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is hacky and dangerous for a file system as a whole.... does the shell this is in matter? does this also have to be for windows?

Comment: You should take a look at the `glob` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: Yes, it has to be for windows and the shell doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make use of the `glob` module.

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob(".../data/")
```

Which will give you a list of files present in the data folder. 
This `glob` module will be useful for your:

> I'm basically asking how to scan a certain directory for a file name. All the files are the same name, so how would I scan the 'data' folder to find them files and append them!

As far as

> as little code as possible

is concerned, I think the regular way should suit you the best.

Note: If you could specify the question in more detail even now, it'd easier to answer. For Example, do you want to change just these two files, or do you want to generalize this to some greater problem? What is your current code and what exactly do you want to avoid doing?

Answer (score 0):

I think `os.walk` is one of the solution here. It can recursively find files in subdirectories. Try this:

```
files_list = [os.path.join(folder,i) for folder, subdirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/data/') for i in files]
```

`files_list` will contain all the files recursively in the `data` folder with absolute path.Now you can search files in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Glob is probably the way to go, it uses roughly the same syntax as command line file specifications, in that wildcards are allowed. So you could do something like:

```
import glob
files=glob.glob("data/file*/*.txt")
for file in files:
    do_thing(file)
```